# RegEx match returns null, but works in online checker

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I'm working on a script to extract data from registration emails and add them to a Google sheet. The script is based on this project: https://gist.github.com/MoayadAbuRmilah/5835369fdebbecf980029f7339e4d769
I want to extract the text that is underneath specific headings, such as 'Namn','Läsår','Personnummer' etc, but the RegEx formulas I'm using doesn't return any matches even though they by all means should work.
Here's a code snippet that should extract the line under the first instance of 'Namn':

```html
var keywords = {
  FullName: "Namn"
};

var msgBody = message.getPlainBody();
Logger.log(msgBody); //Seems to show the entire contents of the email
var regExp;

regExp = new RegExp("(?<="+keywords.FullName+"\\n).*", 'g');
Logger.log(regExp); //Shows up as /(?<=Namn\n)/g in the log, as expected

var studentFullName = msgBody.match(regExp)[0].toString(); //Should return the line under the first 'Namn' heading, but doesn't
```

However, the code fails on the last line with this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at parseNewApplication(Kod:89:57)
    at extractContents(Kod:28:16)
    at importApplications(Kod:14:7)
```

Here's an example e-mail body (with personal details redacted): https://pastebin.com/EXLt2it2
Here's the full script: https://pastebin.com/X2FFRU6K

It's probably something completely obvious that I've overlooked, but at this point I'm kind of lost, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

After reproducing your code by using the ***full script*** and the ***e-mail body example*** I can see there's no issue in your RegEx, the problem shows up when the `msgBody` has not the desired format. To sum up, your RegEx matches `<Name>` only if it's preceded by `Namn\n`.

As a workaround I would use a [Conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `var studentFullName = msgBody.match(regExp) ? msgBody.match(regExp)[0].toString() : "Not Found";` in order to avoid TypeErrors when using your code on different formats.

### Your snippet modified

```
var keywords = {
  FullName: "Namn"
};

var msgBody = message.getPlainBody();
Logger.log(msgBody); //Seems to show the entire contents of the email
var regExp;

regExp = new RegExp("(?<="+keywords.FullName+"\\n).*", 'g');
Logger.log(regExp); //Shows up as /(?<=Namn\n)/g in the log, as expected

var studentFullName = msgBody.match(regExp) ? msgBody.match(regExp)[0].toString() : "Not Found";
```

### Reference

[Regular Expression: Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions)

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely a more graceful way to handle improper formatting, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my original issue. I want to search for a keyword (like "Namn", in this instance), then match whatever is on the next line (in this case it should match <Name>). Any tips on how to do that?

Comment: I reproduced an e-mail like in your example. The code you provided works as expected with the [e-mail example](https://pastebin.com/EXLt2it2) and returns <Name>,<Name>. Probably at some point of your code the message is empty when retrieving the text or it has no "Namn" in it. As I mentioned it's about the message content.

Comment: Well, turns out we're both right; for whatever reason the e-mails use Windows/DOS newlines, i.e. a carriage return (\r) before the line feed (\n). The carriage returns must have been stripped whenever I pasted the e-mail into RegExr or Pastebin, which is why you never encountered the issue. I used string.replace to delete the extra characters, and now everything works as it should.